Where is the error in evaluating this integration:$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}$
Where is the error in evaluating this integration:$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

we have:
$$\int_{C_R}\frac{\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2}dz=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\cos(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx+\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2}dz=2i\pi\text{Res}(f(z),z=i)=\frac{\pi(3-e^4)}{2e^2}$$
and we have :
$$0\le | \int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2}dz | \le \frac{\pi R}{(R^2-1)^2}$$
Let
$$R\to \infty $$
this implies that :$$\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2}dz=0$$
therfore:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\frac{\pi(3-e^4)}{2e^2}$$
but this is result is wrong
Because using wolfram alpha :
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\frac{3\pi}{2e^2}$$

Why do you claim that$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2},\mathrm dz\right|\leqslant\frac{\pi R}{(R^2-1)^2}?$$

How did you calculate the residue? I'm getting a slightly different result.

I realized what mistake I made : $|\cos(z)|<1$

You noticed that $|\cos z|\leq 1$ was a mistake; if this held throughout $\mathbb C$, then $\cos(z)$ would be constant by Liouville's theorem. This led to the incorrect estimate
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2}\right|\leq \frac{\pi R}{(R^2 -1)^2}$$
which I assume came about as follows:
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2}dz\right| &= \left|\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(2\cdot Re^{i\theta})}{(1+( Re^{i\theta})^2)^2}\cdot iRe^{i\theta}d\theta\right|\\
&\leq \int_0^\pi\frac{\left|\cos(2Re^{i\theta})\right|}{\left|1+( Re^{i\theta})^2\right|^2}\cdot \left|iRe^{i\theta}\right|d\theta\\
&= R\int_0^\pi\frac{\left|\cos(2Re^{i\theta})\right|}{\left|1+( Re^{i\theta})^2\right|^2}d\theta &\text{(since $|iRe^{i\theta}|=R$)}\\
&\leq R\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{\left|1+( Re^{i\theta})^2\right|^2}d\theta &{\color{red}{\text{(since $|\cos x|\leq 1$)}}}\\
&\leq \cdots
\end{align*}
The correct bound would be $|\cos(2Re^{i\theta})|\leq |\cos(2Re^{i\pi /2})|=\cosh(2R)$ as $\cos z$ exhibits its maximal growth rate along the imaginary axis, leading to
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2}\right|\leq \frac{\pi  R}{(R^2 -1)^2}\cosh(2R)$$
which is not helpful as the right side is unbounded as $R\to\infty$.

+1 Nice answer :)

@Accelerator thank you!
